# Android Things: Raspberry Pi screen timeout

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things, screen-off

I'm building app on *Raspberry Pi* with *Android Things* and I have [7 inch touch screen](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/45295044-raspberry-pi-7-touch-screen-assembly-guide), but the screen never turns off.

Is it possible to set timeout like in *Android* phones? or force it to turn off/on.

If I remove the power line and inserted again the screen, it will not work until I reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two system settings that control this process: [STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN) and [SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT)

The `STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN` setting is set to `BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC` by default. You can programmatically change this value in your application code with the `Settings` API:

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, 0);
```

You can also make this change from the command line if it is more convenient:

```
$ adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 0
```

Comment: Which method did you use? I just realized there was an error in the shell command.

Comment: The screen is still on, he never go to sleep

Comment: The first suggestion to use STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN throws a permission error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.  However you can't add the permissions to the manifest as permission is only granted for system apps.

Comment: Using SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTING but this is also never granted.  You can check if you have permission using Settings.System.canWrite(this) which always returns false. Using  "adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 0" seems to freeze the display.

Answer (score 2):

*The approach below works starting with Android Things Developer Preview 5.0. For older releases it has no effect.*

**Turn off** display:

```
adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 0
```

**Turn on** display:

```
adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 1
adb shell input keyevent 26
```

For a programmatic solution see @Devunwired's answer.

Comment: Now it is black but the led-backlit is on do you know how to turn it complete off. It will not wake up if I touch the screen. If I insert usb keyboard it will wake up