# Turn off HDMI Output with Android Things on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, hdmi, android-things

I'm creating an Android Things device using a Raspberry Pi 3, which will be connected to monitor. The monitor should be on all of the time, but I'd like a way to "turn off" the device (turning off the HDMI output so that the monitor can go to low-power standby mode) so that I can turn the device on and off remotely or with a timer, rather than having to manually push the monitor's power button.

Is there a way to control the Raspberry Pi's HDMI output (turn the display on or off) in an Android Things project?

Comment: @JC23 I'm not having any problems with the output not being displayed. I'd like to be able to simply turn the HDMI output off/on in my app.

Comment: [Android Things: Raspberry Pi screen timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139985/3290339)