# How to turn off Raspberry Pi screen in Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, screen, raspberry-pi3, android-things

For my smart home application using Android Things and Raspberry Pi I want to be able to turn the connected screen off after a certain amount of running idle and turn it back on after touch input or a command from my connected smartphone app (the smartphone app and notification works fine).

After hours of searching the web for a way to do this and not finding anything working for Android Things 1.0.2, I'm now asking here, how can I do this?

Comment: Tried https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139985/3290339?

Comment: yes, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Because of various screens for Android Things Platforms (NB! none of [Production Platforms](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/#production) now didn't supports HDMI, only "Development" RPi) the only reliable way is to use GPIO pin to control external power switch of your screen (e.g. relay module like in [this](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/google-assistant-smart-home) project if your screen powered by high voltage (110..220V) or schematics like that:

[image: Power switch]

from [that](https://rayshobby.net/wordpress/use-arduino-to-interface-with-a-remote-controlled-power-switch/) project if you screen powered by low voltage (5..36V)). Example for GPIO pin control you can find for example in [Official Basics Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio).

Comment: I thought it would be possible that I just disable HDMI output like in normal linux versions too

Comment: @AlexanderKutschera From [Platform differences](https://developer.android.com/things/get-started/platform-differences#apis) `Android Things is optimized for embedded devices which may not contain the same feature set as an Android phone or tablet. For example, graphical user interfaces are optional as not all devices include a display`.  Also now only [RPi](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/) has HDMI interface and the screens itself can be non-HDMI (SPI or I2c). So very unlikely Android Things V1.02 has HDMI support with power control.