# Android Things 1.06 on Raspbery pi with Screen

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I've been developing on an Android Things PI with a screen and was wanting to turn off the screen via possibly adb shell as I am leaving it on for extended periods of time. Is there a command to run this?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Jeff, take a look at [Android Things: Raspberry Pi screen timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139985/3290339)